# Objective-C with ARC: how to cast from id* to NSString *?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I've got an `id*` type and would like to cast it to an `NSString *` - with ARC enabled. How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**:
This doesn't work... how should I adapt this to make it work?

```
id *idStar = ...;
NSString **string2Star = (NSString **) idStar;
NSLog(@"%@", *string2Star);
```

Comment: `(NSString *)) idStar` won't compile (too many `)`). Is there a typo?

Comment: yes, there was a typo, thanks - but that wasn't the problem...

Comment: yes, I'm using `- (BOOL)validateValue:(id *)value forKey:(NSString *)key error:(NSError **)error`, therefore an `id*` is already provided...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id *` can't be cast to `NSString *` under any circumstances.

Keep in mind that `id` is already a pointer type; making it equivalent not to `NSString`, but to `NSString *`.

In order to cast, you'd have to cast it to `NSString **`.

**Edit:**

In the case you are presenting, the cast is completely unnecessary.

```
NSString *string2Star = *idStar;
```

should do nicely; and even that's moderately unnecessary.

Keep in mind that the variable type in Objective-C basically is nothing more than a hint to the compiler to let it know what methods you are planning to call; and warn you if you call different ones.

The actual method call mapping all happens at runtime; meaning that casts are fairly meaningless.

Comment: You are not casting it to NSString** yet.

Comment: another typo, sorry - still not working: "Pointer to non-const type NSString * with no explicit ownership"